# :not pseudo class doesn't work

Tags: css

I have a style rule:

```
.tabs li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs li:not(:last-child):not(:nth-child(2)):hover {
    background-color: rgba(132,141,149,0.05);
    border-color: rgba(228,230,232,0.25);
}
```

which should change the color of the li's background and border for all elements except second and last element when you mouse over them. But somehow it works for all li elements. What CSS rule should I use?

UPD

saNiks's answer helped me to find a solution. Here is what css code should looks like:

```
.tabs li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(132,141,149,0.05);
    border-color: rgba(228,230,232,0.25);
}

.tabs li:last-child:hover, .tabs li:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: [html code](https://pastebin.com/10yckLSg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rewrite your styles to use the :not selector in applying your desired default style as follows

```
.tabs li {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(132,141,149,0.05);
    border-color: rgba(228,230,232,0.25);
}

.tabs li:not(:last-child):not(:nth-child(2)):hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pkbab5u/)  Code here

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. My style rule should change background and border for all elements except second and last.

Comment: I have redone your code snippet and find the solution on my own. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okies glad that I could be of help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class for the specific `<li>` tag that you want to change, for example:

`<li class="some_class_name"> Some content</li>`

and than to add style to this `<li>` by

`.some_class_name{...
\\your style goes here}`

Comment: Yes, I can but I'm sure there is more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this? If the second item "AND" the last item is to be styled,

```
.tabs li:hover:not(:last-child):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    background-color: rgba(132,141,149,0.05);
    border-color: rgba(228,230,232,0.25);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. My style rule should change background and border for all elements except second and last.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've made the edit which has the one-liner styling (just in case you wanted to use this). Good luck!